# Como fazer o Selenium clicar em um botão gerado dinamicamente?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver

Preciso que o bot faça uma confirmação clicando neste botão, que aparece em um popup:

```
<button class="btn btn-info" id="c2e9772d-375d-47a1-9088-da9824d2e856">Sim</button>
```

Mas o botão em questão parece ser gerado dinamicamente, pois possui um ID diferente a cada transação. Este é o mapeamento que fiz:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ce5597d1-6023-4e63-b3e9-ec2eb4475370")).Click();
```

Existe outra forma de fazer o bot encontrar este botão? Pelo texto, por exemplo? Ou mesmo mandando o bot clicar em uma coordenada específica da janela?

Comment: se ele é renderizado sempre no mesmo lugar, pega ele pelo xpath, vai no código html do site, clica com o direito no html do botão, depois em copy -> xpath.
Depois chama ele pelo xpath -> 
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("xpath aqui ")).Click();

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Apenas um detalhe: usei copy -> copy full XPath.
Com copy XPath não consegui resolver

Comment: publiquei como resposta ali então. flwww

Answer (score -1):

se ele é renderizado sempre no mesmo lugar, pega ele pelo xpath, vai no código html do site, clica com o direito no html do botão, depois em copy -> copy full XPath. Depois chama ele pelo xpath

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("xpath aqui ")).Click();
```